# Equivalence between a simplified function and the original one

Tags: simplifying-expressions

We have a complex function of `Cosh[x]` and `Sinh[x]` which became simplified by Mathematica. Moreover, at the last step, we ourselves, simplified that function more and more. But we are not completely sure that the final obtained function is the simplification of the original function. How we can show the obtained function is equal to the original one.

Although, we cannot write the our function here because it is too long and complicated but we can demonstrate our objective by an example.

Please assume `f[x]=Cosh[x]^2-Sinh[x]^2`, but we cannot show `SameQ[Cosh[x]^2-Sinh[x]^2,1]` or `Cosh[x]^2-Sinh[x]^2==1`!!

Comment: How about plot the difference?

Comment: In our function there are many variables!!

Comment: I find in these sorts of cases the simplest thing to do is to substitute in numerical values.  If an equation is satisfied for completely random parameters, then that lends plausibility that it is always true.

Comment: I have thought this point but this way is not very reliable!!

Comment: Why are you screaming?

Comment: `Cosh[x]^2 - Sinh[x]^2 == 1 // Simplify` In more complicated cases you may need to use `FullSimplify` and/or the option `Assumptions`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, it is very good trick. with your advice I noticed my mistake in simplification and got rid of goofs.